# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username" in Minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, flask-sqlalchemy, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am working on a Multi-Container Flask App, which involves a Web container(Flask app), Postgres container(for DB services), and a Redis container(for Caching services).

Web app has `web_deployment.yaml` and `web_service.yaml` files.
Postgres app has `postgres_deployment.yaml` and `postgres_service.yaml` files.
Redis app has `redis_deployment.yaml` and `redis_service.yaml` files.

My `web_deployment.yaml` file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: my-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-web-app-container
        image: web_app_image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: REDIS_HOST
            value: redis-service
          - name: REDIS_PORT
            value: '6379'
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: username
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            value: postgres-service
          - name: POSTGRES_PORT
            value: '5432'
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: postgres_db
          - name: PGPASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: pgpassword
                key: PGPASSWORD
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: my-web-app
```

The `postgres_deployment.yaml`  file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec: 
      volumes: 
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim 
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts: 
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data 
              subPath: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpassword
                  key: PGPASSWORD
```

While trying to establish connection for web container with the postgres container, I got the following issue:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully fixed it!

The mistake was that, I just mentioned the password in the `posgres_deployment.yaml` file, but I should also mention the database name and the username, using which the `web_deployment.yaml` is trying to access this db service.

Now the new `postgres_deployment.yaml` file, after the correction, looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec: 
      volumes: 
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim 
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts: 
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data 
              subPath: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: username
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres_db
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpassword
                  key: PGPASSWORD
```